# Question on whether or not a given collection is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mathscr F$ be a collection of subsets of $X.$ Let us define $\mathscr F_1,\mathscr F_2, \mathscr F_3$ and $\mathscr F_4$  in the following way.
>
> $\mathscr F_1 : = \mathscr F \cup \{\varnothing\}.$
>
> $\mathscr F_2 : = \mathscr F_1 \cup \left \{A\ |\ A^c \in \mathscr F_1 \right \}.$
>
> $\mathscr F_3 : = \left \{\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\ \bigg |\ A_i \in \mathscr F_2 \right \}.$
>
> $\mathscr F_4 : = \left \{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\ \bigg |\ A_i \in \mathscr F_3 \right \}.$
>
> Is $\mathscr F_4$ a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X\ $?

First I observe that $$\mathscr F \subseteq \mathscr F_1 \subseteq \mathscr F_2 \subseteq \mathscr F_3 \subseteq \mathscr F_4.$$ From here I have managed to prove that $\mathscr F_4$ contains $\varnothing$ and $X$ and it is closed under countable unions. But I am unable to show that $\mathscr F_4$ is closed under complements. What I did myself is as follows $:$

Let $A_i \in \mathscr F_3,$ for $i = 1,2, \cdots.$ Then we need to show that $\left (\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i \right )^c \in \mathscr F_4.$ Since $A_i \in \mathscr F_3,$ for $i = 1,2, \cdots$ there exists $B_{ij} \in \mathscr F_2,$ for $j = 1,2, \cdots$ such that $A_i = \bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} B_{ij}.$ Then $$\left (\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i \right )^c = \left  (\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left ( \bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} B_{ij} \right ) \right )^c.$$ Now since $B_{ij} \in \mathscr F_2$ there exists $C_{ij} \in \mathscr F_1$ such that $B_{ij} = C_{ij}^c.$ So we have $$\begin{align*} \left (\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} A_i \right )^c & = \left  (\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left ( \bigcap\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} C_{ij}^c \right ) \right )^c \\ & = \left  (\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left ( \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} C_{ij} \right )^c \right )^c \\  & =  \bigcap\limits_{i = 1}^{\infty} \left ( \bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{\infty} C_{ij} \right ) \end{align*}$$

Now I got stuck at this stage and couldn't able to proceed further. Would anybody please help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of the above (unless $X$ is a finite set or $\mathcal{F}$ has already some additional structure). Suffices to consider $\mathcal{F}_4$. Start by assuming that $\mathcal{F}$ is merely an ring or an algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, $\mathscr F_4$ will not be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$.

Here is a counter-example.

Let $X= \Bbb R$ and $\mathscr F$ be the set of semi-finite intervals in $\Bbb R$. That is, an element of $\mathscr F$ is of the form $( -\infty, a)$,  $(- \infty, a]$, $(a, \infty)$ or $[a, \infty)$.

Then $\mathscr F_1 : = \mathscr F \cup \{\emptyset\}$  and then

$$\mathscr F_2 : = \mathscr F_1 \cup \left \{A\ |\ A^c \in \mathscr F_1 \right \}= \mathscr F \cup \{\emptyset, \Bbb R\} $$

**Claim**: $\mathscr F_3 : = \left \{\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\ \bigg |\ A_i \in \mathscr F_2 \right \}$ is the set of all intervals in $\Bbb R$ (including the single-element sets as intervals).

**Proof**: Note that all elements of $\mathscr F_2 $ are connected sets in $\Bbb R$ (intervals), so all the elements of $\mathscr F_3$ must be connected sets in $\Bbb R$, that means, intervals. It also easy to see that any interval is the intersection of two semi-finite intervals. $\square$

Now $\mathscr F_4 : = \left \{\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i\ \bigg |\ A_i \in \mathscr F_3 \right \}$ is just the set of countable unions of intervals in $\Bbb R$, which clearly is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

One easy way to see that  $\mathscr F_4 $ is not a $\sigma$-algebra is to note that $\Bbb Q \in \mathscr F_4 $ ($\Bbb Q $ is a countable union of single-point intervals), but $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \notin \mathscr F_4 $( the set of  irrational numbers can not be written as a countable union of intervals).

Comment: Why can't $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ be written as a countable union of intervals? What I think is that If $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ can be written as a countable union of intervals then one of such intervals has to be non-degenerate and hence must have non-empty interior whereas $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ has empty interior. Is my reasoning fine?

Comment: @Phibetakappa Exactly. If $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ could be written as a countable union of intervals, since  $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ is uncountable, one of such intervals should be non-degenerate  and hence must have non-empty interior whereas $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$ has empty interior.

Comment: Another small remark $:$ In the proof you said that all the elements of $\mathscr F_2$ are connected sets, so all the elements of $\mathscr F_3$ must be connected. This is only true for the connected subsets of $\Bbb R$ which are precisely intervals since arbitrary intersection of intervals can easily be proved to be an interval from the definition of intervals. But this argument is no longer valid in arbitrary topological spaces; even in $\Bbb R^2$ this argument fails to hold. A well-known counter-example would be the intersection of a circle with a line which cuts the circle at two points.

Comment: @Phibetakappa The counter-exemple is in $\Bbb R$. I never meant that the intersection of connected sets is connected in general. But it is true in $\Bbb R$.
I have updated the answer to highlight I talking about connected sets in  $\Bbb R$ (intervals).